# How to display an array of objects inside the html template in Angular 2?

Tags: arrays, object, angular, angular-services, angular-pipe

I am building web app that will have a list of 3d models. I’m doing it for a practice purposes, in order to gain some initial knowledge of angular 2.

Each listed model, will have name, main picture, category, and a slider (array of images).

Model data array is:

```
export var MODELS: Model[] = [{ 
  id: 1, 
  name: 'Model 1', 
  image: 'app/img/models/model-1.jpg', 
  category: 'Cat 1',
  slides: [
    { alt: 'Model 1 front view' , url: 'app/img/models/model-2.jpg' },
    { alt: 'Model 1 rear view' , url: 'app/img/models/model-2.jpg' },
    { alt: 'Model 1 side view' , url: 'app/img/models/model-2.jpg' }
  ]  
},
{ 
  id: 2, 
  name: 'Model 2', 
  image: 'app/img/models/model-2.jpg', 
  category: 'Cat 2',
  slides: [
    { alt: 'Model 2 front view' , url: 'app/img/models/model-2.jpg' },
    { alt: 'Model 2 rear view' , url: 'app/img/models/model-2.jpg' },
    { alt: 'Model 2 side view' , url: 'app/img/models/model-2.jpg' }
  ]  

}
];
```

Service that is used for proper displaying of certain model is:

```
@Injectable()
export class ModelService {

  getModels(): Promise<Model[]> {
    return Promise.resolve(MODELS);
  }

  getModel(id: number): Promise<Model> {
    return this.getModels()
           .then(models => models.find(model => model.id === id));
  }
}
```

Model detail’s page template is:

```
<div *ngIf="model">
  <h2>{{model.name}} details!</h2>
  <img [src]="model.image" alt="{{model.name}}"/>
  <div>{{model.slides}}</div>
</div>
```

These are Mostly stuff that I used from: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/

However, when I try to use simplest way to display slides array into model-detail page, it shows [object Object]. I read that this is might be a common issue in angular 2,  that can be resolved by using custom pipes. Unfortunately, I have no clue how to write one for this certain case.

General question will be:  How to properly display array of objects (slides) on html template, and wrap them separately into **img** tag.

Here is plunker example link: http://plnkr.co/edit/HVo3dtGprMHsPYeyRWBR?p=preview

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because your `slides` property is in fact an `Object`, it's an array so displaying the property alone will simply display 'object'. What you need to do is iterate over the slides property and separately create img divs:

```
<img *ngFor="let slide of model.slides" [alt]="slide.alt" [src]="slide.url" />
```

this is what your updated template would look like from your plunkr:

```
<ul class="models">
      <li *ngFor="let model of models" (click)="gotoDetail(model)">
      <img *ngFor="let slide of model.slides" [src]="slide.url"/>
      {{model.name}},{{model.category}}
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Syntactic, it really not showing [object Object] any more,  but instead it writes "slide.alt slide.alt slide.alt", also cannot show any image url. Should i do something more ?

Comment: Even on your local machine? It won't display and images on plunkr because you don't have them on there, if you use the code I pasted in the edit it should work on your local machine so let me know if it doesn't

Comment: Syntactic,  this last snippet works for models page,  but i need it on model-detail page, when i try to apply it there,  app breaks

Comment: Sorry Syntactic,  it is working even on details page,  I wrote wrong. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

You could use *ngFor in an img tag I have included some of my practice code to show you what I mean.

```
<div class="col-md-6" *ngFor="let picture of imageUrl; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
                    <div class="portfolio-item"
                        style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                        <a (click)="galleryOpen = false;componentIndex = i;" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" name="gal2">
                            <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src={{picture}} height="350" width="455"
                                style="height: 350px; max-width: 455px;">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The *ngFor in this case could just a easily be placed in the img tag. I hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thank you T.Morrell for contributing to this question. Will check this code later on,  just to see if somehow fits into my particular case.